# Как предоставить разрешение с помощью .htaccess для определенного имени файла (SCRIPT_FILENAME)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions

Можно ли с помощью .htaccess разрешить загрузку файла из папки только с помощью определенного PHP скрипта?

Скрипт из myfile.php может скачивать файлы из папки, а скрипты с другим именем файла - не могут.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь скорее нужно сделать пользователей на сервере и запускать скрипт от пользователя с правами разрешаюшими скачивать файлы из папки.
или
Можно в .htaccess настроить AuthType Basic, а в скрипте myfile.php выполнить HTTP-аутентификацию. ( но тут учтите, передача паролей в запросе, не очень безопасно )